# number of local extrema of a $f(x)= \sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: limits, derivatives

> Consider the function $f(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x}$. Find a positive integer $N$ such that the
> number of local extrema of $f$ over the open interval $(\frac{1}{N}, 1)$is precisely $2020$.

Please help me find what is the value of $N$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: These local extrema would have to satisfy a certain necessary condition. Something about derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

There is exactly one local extremum in the interval $\left[\frac{1}{N}, \frac{1}{N-2\pi}\right]$

Now you need to find $N$ for which there will be $2020$ such intervals in $\left(\frac{1}{N}, 1\right)$